# Сено/солома

Tags: этимология

Известна история (или байка?) о том, как учили неграмотных рекрутов разбирать, где "право", а где "лево". Привязывали к одной ноге сено, к другой - солому, да так и командовали: сено - солома - сено - солома.

Имеет ли эта история под собой основания? Неужели люди, пусть даже самые простые, не знали этих слов и понятий? Когда и как появились в языке слова "правый" и "левый"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ЛЕВЫЙ** «расположенный в той стороне тела, где находится сердце», «расположенный с левой стороны». Древн. слав, слово. Сохраняет свое первонач. знач. Имеет соответствия в других и.-е. языках. Соврем. форма данного слова развилась из стар. лѢвыи. На рус. почве в ней Ѣ изменился в Е. Ср. укр. лівий — тожд., где Ѣ дал I. Др.-рус. лѢвый "левый", "неправильный", "злой" < от и.-е. основы *laiu-o- (ср.: лат. laevus, греч. λαιός) Старшее значение, по-видимому, "неправильный", "кривой", "слабый".

**ПРАВЫЙ** «расположенный в стороне, противоположной левой». Древн. слав. слово. Полная его форма *правый* образована от праслав. кратк. *рravъ > правъ > прав «прав». Происхождение праслав. слова достоверной этимол. не имеет. Одни считают, что* рravъ, возможно, возникло в результате скрещения (контаминации) *рrĕmъ «прямой» и* оrv-ьn-ъ «ровный». Другие полагают, что праслав. *рrаvъ развилось из и.-е.* prōuos «вперед направленный, впереди находящийся». На слав. почве долгий ō дал а, неслоговой u > v, а оконч. -os > -ъ. Слово *prouos образовано с суф. -u-os > -v-ъ от* рrō-, того же, что предл. про со знач. «перед, впереди». Прил. *рravъ > правъ первонач. значило «вперед направленный», откуда дальнейшие знач.: «прямой, ровный» и «истинный, такой, как надо». Сравнивают его с лтш. pravs «значительный, видный», лат. probus «хороший». От* правый*1 «такой, как надо» —* правый*2 «ни в чем не виноватый».

Крестьяне, набранные в армию, конечно, имели представление о том, что такое право и лево. Только правая рука называлась десница, а левая - шуйца. А различать *правый* "прямой" и *левый* "кривой" для них было так же трудно, как для теперешних городских жителей - сено и солому.

Comment: Очень интересно! А когда же слова "правый" и "левый" приобрели современный смысл "сторон тела"? И почему это смысл по-разному распространялся в народной и "элитарной" среде?  

И еще: почему представление о сердце (левой стороне) связано со злом? Вообще не очень понятно, какой смысл тут первичен.

Comment: Ходить "налево" - неправильно! )))

Comment: @DocentI, нужно поднять исторические словари (по векам). К сожалению, под рукой сейчас их нет. Может быть, кто-нибудь найдет ответ быстрее. Если эту тему серьезно исследовать, можно и дисеертацию написать :-))

Comment: @DocentI, о том, почему в разных языках левый - "плохой", нашла кое-что здесь (не совсем научно, но все-таки!): http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/i-wolga/post231675754/ С сердцем это никак не связано.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Действительно, связь правоты с правой рукой кажется естественной.

Answer (score 1):

Где-то читал версию, что "сено-солома" было придумано в Петровские времена, как известно, во времена Петра создавалась первая русская регулярная армия, которая строилась по немецким образцам. Соответственно, большинство офицеров были немцы, которые отдавали команды на немецком: *rechts-links* - оттуда и возникала путаница.

Comment: Версия правдоподобная!

Answer (score 1):

Про сено-солому ничего не могу сказать, а вот про отношение правой стороны к моральной правоте читала. У древних славян мир делился на три части - правь (мир богов), явь (повседневный мир), и навь (мир умерших, теней, нечести): сразу заметна причина "правосудия", "правильности", и "правоты". "Правильно" вести себя следуя подобию и примеру богов.

Теперь про "право" как указатель направления. Славяне, как и многие другие народы, почитали солнце как наиглавнейшее божество. Живя на северном полушарии, они следили за солнцем когда оно шло от востока к югу к западу. Если сделать такой поворот, то он получится по часовой стрелке - иначе говоря, в правую сторону. Люди следовали за солнцем в мир прави, и шли "на право".

Индо-европейский символ свастики у славян назывался коловратом (коло=колесо=солнце, врат=вращение). Если представить на секунду что коловрат - настоящее колесо, то понятно что оно катится в направление противоположеном направлению лучиков. Если верхний луч смотрит на право, колецо катится на лево, и наоборот. И так, коловрат, "катящийся" налево, против часовой стрелки, катится к нави и обозначает движение к смерти, потерю энергии. Напротив, коловрат катящийся направо символизирует жизнь. Меня всегда порожало как когда-то язык на столько больше перекликался а жизнью и духовной символикой; язык значил на много больше чем сегодня. Куда нам с нашими "окейями" тягаться!

Этимологически, правый значил прямой, но это тоже берёт корни в прави - прямая, неискаженная душа у праведного человека, избравшего правый путь (напрашивается сравнение с выражением "кривить душой"). "Левый" как раз значило "кривой", "изогнутый". Это сходство есть и в германских языках. Я смотрела этимологию английских слов "right" и "left", и нашла те же корни, но без красивой связи к легендам или божествам. Наверное, сходство объясняется теорией индо-европейского проишождения, а разница - смесью народов и языков которые исторически меняли и культ и язык жителей нынешней Великобритании.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что байка о неграмотных крестьянах с сеном и соломой не имеет под собой оснований. Современные значения - достаточно древние. Дело в том, что "шуя" и "десна" означали только руки, для положения относительно человека использовались прнятия "одесную" и "ошую". В отношении самих понятий "правый" и "левый" применение этих терминов было невозвожно. Ну не скажешь же "со стороны правой руки дома или дороги"? Нет у домов ручек. Ножки - и те только курьи. А были бы - еще непонятно, как бы сложилось обозначение сторон.

Кстаи, кто-нибудь замечал, что "справа от меня" и "справа от дома" означают прямо противовположные вещи?

Comment: >Ну не скажешь же "со стороны правой руки дома или дороги"? Нет у домов ручек.
Возможно, "по правую руку"?

Comment: Так вот и подумайте, что получится. Даже если предположить, что у дома есть руки. Сразу поймете разницу между понятиями ошую/одесную и справа/слева.